# How do I convert date in VBA with format "YYYYMMDD HHMMSS"?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have my datetime stored as string:

```
"20120515 061115"
```

would be

```
"May 15, 2012 at 6 hour 11 minutes 15 second"
```

How do I convert this to datetime?  Maybe using the "CDate" function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input format for `CDate` depends on your system locale, which makes it useless for parsing values that come in a fixed format.

However, since your date components are at fixed positions, the simplest way is to use string functions to extract the values from the original string:

```
Dim s As String
Dim d As Date

s = "20120515 061115"
d = DateSerial(Left(s, 4), Mid(s, 5, 2), Mid(s, 7, 2)) _
  + TimeSerial(Mid(s, 10, 2), Mid(s, 12, 2), Mid(s, 14, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this in a query by parsing the date and then reconstructing it:

In this example my UglyDate looks like this:
Wed Mar 17, 2010  10:07 PM

```
SELECT [Tbl_UglyDate].[UglyDate], Mid([UglyDate],5,3) AS M, Mid([UglyDate],9,2) AS D,
Mid([UglyDate],13,4) AS Y, Month("1 " & [M]) AS M2, 
([M2] & "/" & [D] & "/" & [Y]) AS date1, CVDate([date1]) AS [date] 
FROM [Tbl_UglyDate];
```